# Laravel - Get the first entry of every day a row was created

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

i am making a app with laravel to track my workouts. The fields in the database are: id, created_at, updated_at, exercise, repetitions and weight.

I want to make kind of a timeline of all the workouts. Timeline should be a list of all the dates that i did a workout.

My problem is: How do i get the first entry for every date i did a workout?

Comment: You could have a **date** field with date format "Y-m-d", then group by that field.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using something like mysql and have a table such as 'workouts', with the columns you provided, this should do the trick.

```
DB::table('workouts')
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
    ->groupBy(DB::raw('DATE(created_at)'))
    ->get();
```

This essentially selects * from the table workouts, then orders it by the created_at column in ascending order, then groups the created_at column, so only 1 entry from each date is retrieved. The 'DB::raw('DATE('created_at'))' is needed to create the created_at field as a mysql date object (by default laravel uses a date time for its timestamps).

Answer (score -1):

You should really take a different approach to this with Laravel. If you have a `Workout` object, and each of those has `Exercises` associated with it, what you're wanting to do becomes really easy:

Models:

- Workout
- Exercise

Tables:

```
workout
id | created_at | updated_at

exercises
id | workout_id | exercise | repetitions | weight | created_at | updated_at
```

in your Workout model:

```php
public function exercises() {
    return $this->hasMany(App\Excercise::class);
}
```

Then in your controller you can do:

```
<?php

$workouts = App\Workout::all();

foreach ($workouts as $key => $workout) {
    $exercises = $workout->exercises;
    // do stuff
}
```

And to get your timeline you can do something like:

```php
$workouts = App\Workout::groupBy(DB::raw('Date(created_at)'))->get();
```

which will get all your workouts grouped by the day they were done.